# Cleveref and pdf Bookmark

Tags: hyperref, pdf, cleveref, bookmarks

I'm making pdf bookmarks with hyperref and cleveref packages. However, the pdf bookmarks show the label I defined, rather than the theorem name the label refers to. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{theorem}\label{some label}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{Proof to \Cref{some label}}

\end{document}
```

And here's the pdf:
[image]

Any idea how to change the label to "Proof to Theorem 1" instead of "Proof to some label"?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\Cref` is not really expandable, I fear, since it's defined to be a robust command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no solution for this, apart from using the command `\texorpdfstring`, that is you have to specify what has to go in the text and what has to go in the bookmarks.

Hence, substitute

```
\section{Proof to \Cref{some label}}
```

with

```
\section{Proof to \texorpdfstring{\Cref{some_label}}{Theorem \ref{some_label}}}
```

Note that it isn't a good idea to have label names with spaces, so I've substituted `some label` with `some_label`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{theorem}\label{some_label}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{Proof to \texorpdfstring{\Cref{some_label}}{Theorem \ref{some_label}}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That solves the problem (with a bit more work), thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The `\Cref` command cannot be used in `\section` when bookmarks are being produced; however, `\autoref` works (it's less powerful, though). For a simple application like this you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\Cref\autoref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{theorem}\label{some_label}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{Proof to \Cref{some_label}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did try [tag:autoref], but I do have a bunch of lemmas/propositions/corollaries which makes [tag:cleveref] more suitable.

Comment: @ErikaL Yes, but as you see, I let `\Cref` to `\autoref` only in bookmarks where super precision is not really necessary.

Comment: It does work for the MWE. However I found another strange behavior using this method, see [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235634/discrepancy-between-thm-and-theorem]

Comment: This answer deserves to be upvoted more. It is an automatic solution relative to the manual solution that the accepted answer proposes. The virtues are obvious. If a figure number being referred to in the bookmark/section heading changes, then hand-coding a string quickly becomes dangerously out of date & misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik)'s solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485979/128042
one can use the `crossreftools` package together with some custom code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \let\Cref\crtCref
    \let\cref\crtcref
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{theorem}\label{some_label}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{Proof to \Cref{some_label}}

\end{document}
```

This automatically creates the correct pdf bookmarks (in TexXStudio one has to compile it two times). (If you are also interested in removing the color of the links, see  [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik)'s solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485979/128042.)

<sub>PS: This answer was also improved by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s comment on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504970/128042 (answering the equivalent question [automatic \texorpdfstring for \ref in pdf bookmarks (section titles)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504968/automatic-texorpdfstring-for-ref-in-pdf-bookmarks-section-titles)).</sub>