# Discrepancy between "thm" and "theorem"

Tags: hyperref, pdf, cleveref, bookmarks

The command `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}` and `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` produce different pdf bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\Cref\autoref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{thm}\label{label_1}
    This is theorem 1.
\end{thm}
\begin{theorem}\label{label_2}
    This is theorem 2.
\end{theorem}

\section{Proof to \Cref{label_1}}
\Cref{label_1}

\section{Proof to \Cref{label_2}}
\Cref{label_2}

\end{document}
```

We can see that they produce different pdf bookmarks---the one generated by thm only says "1" rather than "Theorem 1". Can anyone tell me why this would happen?
[image: Generated Pdf]

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence Fixed---sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\autoref` knows only a basic set of names; just teach it what it should substitute for `thm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\Cref\autoref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\thmautorefname}{Theorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{thm}\label{label_1}
    This is theorem 1.
\end{thm}
\begin{theorem}\label{label_2}
    This is theorem 2.
\end{theorem}

\section{Proof to \Cref{label_1}}
\Cref{label_1}

\section{Proof to \Cref{label_2}}
\Cref{label_2}

\end{document}
```

My impression is that this is a false problem: do you *really* need to use `\Cref` in that case? After all a section devoted to a proof will surely be about a theorem.

[image]

Comment: Wonderful. As I said I have lemmas/propositions/corollaries which has long proofs, so I'm afraid \Cref should still be my first choice. Thank you!

Comment: @ErikaL I'd simply go with `\pdfstringdefDisableCommand{\let\Cref\ref}`: the bookmarks will just have the numbers, but it doesn't seem such an important thing.

Comment: @egreg which tex editor are you using?

Comment: @vejn That's the screen shot by Skim; I (almost) never use an editor with an integrated previewer. Sometimes I use TeXShop or TeXworks, mostly for didactic purposes. For bigger projects I use Aquamacs, for making examples here I normally use `nano` from the terminal. I simply can't stand TeXStudio or Texmaker.

Comment: @egreg digressing here, but how about `vim` with `vimtex` for the editor and `zathura` (linux)/`skim` (mac) for the viewer?

Comment: @Krishna Are you joking? `;-)` You should [look at my office door](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEOOE.jpg). `:-D`

Comment: Just curious about why the elder geeks here (like you & David) so emacs-y? I wrote my entire PhD thesis in `vim`

Comment: @Krishna I once tried `vi`, but wasn't able to exit from it and I had to change computer. `;-)`